# Windows 10 - "Sort by Date" but with files on top?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, zip, sorting, date

I've noticed that for some reason, anything I unzip uses some other Modified by Date that is far older than when the folder was unzipped on my PC, that makes it very annoying to go through my files. This wasn't an issue on Windows 7 (I'm a newq Win10 user), so by Googling, I found out that sorting by "Date" actually works better, and so it does.

The only issue is that it puts folders on top, and I want the files to be on top, while the folders at the bottom, still sorted by date. 
That was entirely possible to do on Windows 7 and unzipped folders/files didn't have this weird behavior, but either I can't remember how it was done or maybe something changed in Win10.

If anyone has a solution, including third party applications, please do tell, thank you.

Comment: Folders go to the top on my Windows 7 machine. Still true in Windows 10.  In Windows 10, I tried Windows Explorer, xPlorer2, and Total Commander.  Only Command Window DIR does it differently

Comment: Comment on the weird date behavior.  Take a close look at files whose Date Modified is earlier than Date Created.  The only way this can happen is if the contents were copied from some other source, like a zip file, and if the process that made the copy propagated the Date Modified from the source file to the copy, while the Date Created was the Date the copy was made.  This behavior was pretty standard in the unzippers I have used for a long time.

Comment: @John I don't want folders on top, I want the files on top. Also Walter, I didn't have that issue in Windows 7.

Comment: There is no practical way to do that. Windows has put folders on top for many years

Comment: It doesn't do so with Sort by Date Modified, but the issue remains that the inside-ZIP dates are making me suffer. There should be a way to change this.